# Wordpress plugin & PHP choose selected element from a drop down menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I have these 2 functions of the same class. I need to retrive the selected element from the drop down menu but I can not. What am I doing wrong??

```
    global $wpdb;

    $results =$wpdb -> get_col("SELECT `user_login` FROM `wp_users`");

    echo'<form method="post">
    <select name="employees" id="employees">';

    foreach ($results as $value) {
        echo'<option value="' .$value . '" ">  ' .$value. '</option>"';
     }
 
 '</select>';



echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="first_name" value="' .var_dump($_POST). '" placeholder="Write your First Name">';
echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="first_name" value="' .var_dump($_POST['employees']). '" placeholder="Write your First Name">';
echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="first_name" value="' .print_r($_POST['employees']). '" placeholder="Write your First Name">';
```

Comment: Have you done a `print_r($_POST)` to see what your page actually receives?

Comment: `print_r($_POST)`  result is 1          
`var_dump($_POST) ` results is array(0) { }                                 
`var_dump($_POST['employees'])`  result is Warning: Undefined array key "employees" in /opt/lampp/htdocs

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['emp'])`  result is Warning: Undefined array key "emp" in /opt/lampp/htdocs ........–

Comment: _"print_r($_POST) result is 1 var_dump($_POST)  results is array(0) { }"_ - this seems inconsistent already, the print_r output for an empty array should be `Array()`, not `1`, see https://3v4l.org/LLdik

Comment: _"I have these 2 functions of the same class."_ - and where & when are those called?

Comment: This class is a call back. It is called from Admin.php file on load using the following file:

`public function setFields()
 {
  
   array(
    'id' => 'first_name',
    'title' => 'Stunde / woche',
    'callback' => array( $this->callbacks, 'alecadddFirstName' ),
    'page' => 'alecaddd_plugin',
    'section' => 'alecaddd_admin_index',
    'args' => array(
     'label_for' => 'first_name',
     'class' => 'example-class'
    )
   )
  );

  $this->settings->setFields( $args );
 }`

Comment: I added everything on the same function and still the same result..... :(((

Answer (score 0):

I had this code on the pagename.php which calls the callback class where was located my dropdownlis.

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php 
                settings_fields( 'alecaddd_options_group' );
                do_settings_sections( 'alecaddd_plugin' );
                submit_button();
            ?>
        </form>
```

After removing the action fild everything worked great